# Blender 4.0 Video Sequence Editor audio pitch missing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, audio

In Video Sequence Editor, there was no pitch setting. I looked on the internet for help and it told me that it changed from pitch setting from the sound section to the speed factor on the time section but in Blender 4.0, it doesn't show the speed factor setting at all.

Answer (score 4):

The option *Speed Factor* is no longer existing in 4.0, still under *Time* though you now find the new option *Show Retiming Keys* which is disabled by default.

Enabling it you will now show two keys on the sound strip at the beginning and the end:

[image: retiming keys]

If you now drag for example the end key to the left, the strip gets shorter and you can see an increasing percentage, which is the factor of the speed with which the sound will be played. In my image it's 180%, meaning the sound will play 1.8 times faster:

[image: faster speed]

Of course you could also move it to the right to slow it down or move the start key to the left or right.

What you can also do now is go to the *Strip* menu, then *Retiming* > *Add Retiming Key* (or hit <kbd>I</kbd>) and it will add a key on the frame where the playhead is currently located:

[image: set retiming key]

Now there's three keys, start and end key and one in the middle. To the left and right on the strip it says 100%, so everything plays at normal speed.

[image: new retiming key]

Now you can drag this key in the middle of the sound strip to the left or right. In my example I drag it to the left: the left side of the strip gets now played at a speed of 220%. The key at the end is not moved, so the right side of the strip plays at 70%, to maintain the overall length of the sound:

[image: creating two different speeds]

If you want the speed after the middle key to stay at 100%, you need to move two keys, the one in the middle and the one at the end so that they keep their offset.

There are other functions in the *Retiming* menu as well, but I have not explored them yet since I did not do much with sound in 4.0 so far. This was just a quick information where you find the sound's speed manipulation now.

In my eyes this is an improvement to the previous implementation, for one you no longer need to split up the sound strip if you want different speeds on the same strip.

Secondly you can now actually see a change in the length of a strip according to the time it takes to play it. Before, a changed speed factor was not visible and you could not see how long the sound wouldtake to play.

Comment: Thanks, nice improvement, a bit bugged though but I guess they will fix that

Comment: @moonboots Bugged? In which way, haven't experienced that so far (but as stated in the answer, did not do much audio editing in 4.0 so far).

Comment: So far, it seems hard to select a key if I have another adjacent sound strip and deleting a key has made Blender crash...

Comment: @moonboots Yeah, selecting them is a bit tricky. Deleting keys I had no problems yet.